# Skype installed or not installed, that is the question

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, skype

After upgrading 11.10 to 12.04, I noticed that Skype 2.2.0.35 was no longer on the sidebar of icons.  Found it in Dash and it runs but no sound.  Figured I'd check Ubuntu Software Center and reinstall but it indicates a different version - 2.2.0.35-0precise3 - and indicates that Skype is not installed.  Attempting to go ahead and install errors saying that it can't install when skype is already installed.

```
sudo apt-get remove skype
```

...then it says

```
Package skype not installed
```

Tried to update apt-get but that didn't make any difference.

Seems like it would be best to straighten this all out so it's right and, presumably, the newer version is probably better to have installed.  Can anyone step me through how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug. Try to install the package of Synaptic, search the word skype, then uninstall everything relative to it. Finally try to install it again from Software Center and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get purge skype skype-bin
```

Then install the new version (I recommend 4.0) from [Skype.com](http://skype.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

To remove skype and config files, but not dependences using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove skype
```

To remove unused dependencies and config files using apt-get

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

Or you can use Synaptic Package Manager:  Search for skype, and Once you've found it, right-click on it or left click on the green icon and select Mark for Complete Removal.

Then you can use USC to install the new version of Skype.